# NodeJS, usage of private ca with express.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, openssl

I am trying to create an https/express server with a server certificate signed by a custom CA.
Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

var config     = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('cert/server.key'),
 cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/server.crt'),
   ca: fs.readFileSync('cert/ca.crt')
};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello world');
});


https.createServer(config,app).listen(443);
```

Here is how i create my CA and my server cert :

```
### CA self signed
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 1024
openssl req -new -key ca.key -out ca.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in ca.csr -signkey ca.key -out ca.crt


### server cert signed by CA
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server_pass.key 1024
openssl rsa -in server_pass.key -out server.key
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey ca.key -out server.crt
```

I don’t think I’m doing it wrong on the openssl part, I create my CA, by definition auto-signed, then I create my server key and csr and then sign it with my CA cert.
I have tried this same nodeJS code with à directly self-signed certificate and in that case it works well.

I assume the problem is that my server cert is neither auto signed nor signed by a public CA as if express didn’t used my custom ca in the config object.

Can someone confirm or invalidate my supposition?

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: Is it throwing some error, or does connecting from a browser just fail?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found out I was using the wrong parameter when signing my key.

I was using: `-signkey ca.key`

but I should use, when the signing element is a CA file: `-CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial`

Now it works